# Python ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: dll, kivy, python-3.4

```
python34
windows 8.1 64-bit
```

So I just installed Kivy after installing the dependencies, the whole process went very well until I used Kivy's simple "Hello World!" application on their website, which is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='kfkdnf')

TestApp().run()
```

And this error popped up:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I tried different solutions like reinstalling Kivy and the other dependencies but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run with below command to print more info. first.

```
"python main.py -c kivy:log_level:trace"
```

If it happens after load fbo.pyx, you may try this solution:

Try `copy glew32.dll` from "share\glew\bin\glew32.dll" to "`Lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\`".

Analysis: I met the same issue. And found that the error happens when you simply try to "`import kivy.graphics.opengl`".

Generally, almost any kind of DLL missing issue can be solved by using process monitor (`procmon.exe`) from Sysinternals Suite.

Run procmon.exe, add a new filter and click OK. "`Process Name`" "is" "`python.exe`"

Then in toolbar, only leave file system activity, and close other view.

Now open a python session and run "import kivy.graphics.opengl". As expected there is error shows "DLL load failed". Also, many activity shows in procmon about file system activities.

Do not try to sort since by default it's sorted by time and it's useful for debugging.

Check the result column for the "NAME NOT FOUND" event. Generally, an executable will search the DLL in current folder, then in pre-defined path, then in system environment "PATH". If you see a "NAME NOT FOUND" event on some module, try search the module name in "PATH" column, if it's always "NAME NOT FOUND" but no "SUCCESS", it's the missing DLL you are finding. Copy the file to the path which it's searched at first.

In my case, I found `glew32.dll` is always "`NAME NOT FOUND`". Since one of the dependency of Kivy is `kivy.deps.glew`, use any PE tool check `\Lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\opengl.pyd`, found that one of the DLL dependency of `opengl.pyd` is `glew32.dll`, so its confirmed the result from process monitor, that `glew32.dll` is required to be imported by `opengl.pyd (dll)`.

So I copied glew32.dll from "`share\glew\bin\`" to "`\Lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\"`.

The issue is solved on my side.

All other DLL missing issue can be solved by using Process Monitor. Hope the suggestion helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bad compilation or something in this way happened. Maybe you have too high version of Cython? Basically you are missing a part of an important file that should be compiled, maybe something from `kivy.graphics`. Uninstall kivy, reinstall deps. If you are trying to compile from source, then install `mingwpy` which is mentioned in the docs.

Or use the wheel, which is already compiled source for windows (there are links, you just need to rename and install).

Or use [KivyInstaller](http://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller).

Also, try to search "kivy DLL not found" in google and you'll get some links to SO too. There was an [issue at github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1355), so try those steps too.

Comment: I reinstalled kivy and the deps. The same problem occurs. And I think it's something from kivy.graphics but it's not just that. Here's the whole error: http://i.imgur.com/zT0MsZp.jpg?1

Comment: Yes, `fbo` is mentioned in the issue I posted in my answer. There it looks like solved.

Comment: Now I tried that solution as well in the issue you mentioned, that's what happened (2 different results when I closed and reopened the shell): http://i.imgur.com/ooq7m7G.jpg?1

Comment: Did kivy fail to start the app in both cases? If yes, report it at [irc](https://kivy.org/#support).

Comment: Didn't try to start kivy in the first case, which occurred just once, and yes, in the second case it failed. Thanks for your help anyway.